# Como simular um "min-top" em css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Alguém conhece uma maneira de simular um "`min-top`" em um elemento? Talvez utilizando JS ou Jquery...
Estou usando o `scale()` em um objeto, porém a função faz com que o elemento mude de posição. 
Gostaria que ao aplicar `scale()` o objeto sempre fique abaixo desse elemento de position absolute... Seria possível ?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .papel {width: 297mm;height: 210mm; background-color:#CCC;border: 3px solid gray;top: -45%;left: 0%;position: absolute; overflow:hidden;transform:scale(0.5) translate3d(0px,0px,0px); margin-bottom: 80px;transform: translate3d(73px,521px,0px);}
    .mover{position:absolute; cursor:move;}
    #menu{width:100%;height:150px;background-color:blue;}
</style>

<div id="range-input">
        <input type="range" id="zoompapel" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.1" />
</div>

<div id="menu">
    MENU SUPERIOR
</div>
<div class="papel mover" id="papel">
  TESTE
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#zoompapel').change(function(event) {
        var value = $('#zoompapel').val();
           $('#papel').css({
              '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + value + ')',
              '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + value + ')',
              '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + value + ')',
              '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + value + ')',
              'transform'         : 'scale(' + value + ')'});
            $("#papel").css('position','absolute');

 });
</script>
```

Comment: passe o código e ajudo, existe vários min de css avançado, veja também SASS.

Comment: @KingRider Exibi o código para melhor compreensão...Não gostaria que a div papel ultrapasse a div menu...

Comment: _user48796: eu vi código, porque esta usando val() ? e veja diferença de posição http://i.imgur.com/X2MObbG.png ... você quer animação passar mouse para abrir caixa lado menu é isso? posso fazer para você.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    min-height:50px;
    background-color: #fee;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}
#div2 {
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: #efe
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/5051/

Resultado:

Quando a div1 esta oculta, div2 tem a propriedade top de 50px

Quando a div1 não esta oculta:

Se a div1 tem altura menor que 50px, então div2 é posicionada a 50px.

Se a div1 tem mais de 50px de altura, a div2 é posicionada logo abaixo da div1.

Tradução de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552358/is-there-a-css-min-top-property